# jquery variable undefined but console shows it holds a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below image shows the result of `console.log(data)` in the following block of code, but console.log(data.result) returns `undefined`. At first I thought it was an array, but `data[0].result` and `data[0]` both show undefined. Also weird to me, if I put `console.log(data.bitrate)` or contentRange, or so on, they all return values.

[image: Console.log]

This is the code I'm using it in, fileupload is from a library [here](https://github.com/blueimp)

```js
$(function() {
  var maxChunkSize = .5 * 1024 * 1024; //SET CHUNK SIZE HERE (.5 mb)

  $('.PicturesForm').fileupload({
    maxChunkSize: maxChunkSize,
    url: 'forms/vehicle_Pictures.cfm', //URL WHERE FILE TO BE UPLOADED
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // Called for each failed chunk upload
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      /*This event will be called on success of upload*/
      var count = parseInt($(this.form).find('[name=counter]').val()) + 1;
      $(this.form).find('[name=counter]').val(count);
    },
    submit: function(e, data) {
      /*This event will be called on submit here i am adding variable to form*/
      $(this).find('[name=fileName]').val(data.originalFiles[0].name);
      $(this).find('[name=numberOfChunks]').val(Math.ceil(data.originalFiles[0].size / maxChunkSize));
      $(this).find('[name=counter]').val('1');
    },
    progress: function(e, data) {
      console.log(data.bitrate);
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data[0]);
      console.log(data[0]);
      console.log(data[0].result);
      $(this).find('[name=progressBar]').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: See that blue `[i]` that appears when you expand the object? Mouse-over that.

Comment: Okay, I get that it shows that because it's evaluated when I click on it; does that mean I can evaluate it somehow and get that same value?

Comment: You need to access it when it's ready to be accessed. The `progress` function is certainly not going to have a `result` value. `success`, however, might.

Comment: Ah, spot on. I completely missed that.